# Zoom-in and then while drawing shape zoom-out

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing, zoom

How can I zoom-out when zoomed-in at a certain percentage, while drawing a shape.  That means after I've clicked on the canvas, and start drawing, but have not released the mouse.  Thanks.

Comment: You want to zoom in or out _while_ you are drawing?

Comment: either or but i was looking to zoom out while i was drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not. It is simply not possible in Illustrator.